# Selenium 2 Inject CSS into currently displayed web page

Tags: java, javascript, css, selenium-webdriver

I tested the following jQuery on a jQueryfied page to inject custom CSS code to the page:

```
jQuery('head').append('<style type=\"text/css\">body { background: #000; }</style>');
```

After that, the background of the page immediately turns black, so far so good. But if i try that with Selenium 2 (Java), i do not see any reaction:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("jQuery('head').append('<style type=\"text/css\">body { background: #000; }</style>');");
```

jQuery is loaded correctly. Any ideas why that does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why use an awkward style tag injection that depends on jQuery? Why not use something simple like

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
```

Comment: because i want to extend an existing web page with jquery ui, which includes a big css file

Comment: I'm not sure why your syntax doesn't work - but the following works for me in WebDriver: Browser.ExecuteScript("$('<style type=\"text/css\">body{background-color: black;}</style>').appendTo('html > head');");

Comment: ok it works now, the code is good. it was a problem in my application which didnt correctly execute the js code.

Comment: attached the selenium call for modifying the page's css within Java:
`code`((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript("$('<style type=\"text/css\">body{background-color: white;}</style>').appendTo('html > head');");`code`